# efficiently serialize a fractions.Fraction

Tags: python

I have lots of large [`fraction.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) numbers.

I want to write them to a file using as few bytes as possible.

The `fraction.Fraction` class is an unmarshallable object.

So I cannot marshal it, and writing the numerator and denominator separately would take lots and lots of space.

Comment: are you looking to write to a pickle?

Comment: realistically, if you want to preserve it as a symbolic fraction you need at least the same number of bytes as writing the numerator and denominator separately. serializing the whole object would also include attributes included by the `fractions.Fraction` class such as: `imag`, `conjugate`, etc. The smallest you're going to get is still likely going to be writing the numerator and denominator separately.

Comment: also cPickle sort of works... `>>>cPickle.dumps(fractions.Fraction('7/23')`:  `"cfractions\nFraction\np1\n(S'7/23'\ntRp2\n." `